# How to create text connection from string variable?

Tags: r

This should be quick to answer:

I want to use jags packages' `jags.model` function. Among many arguments it needs the argument `file`:

> `file` - the name of the file containing a description of the model in
>   the JAGS dialect of the BUGS language.
>
> Alternatively, file can be a
>   readable text-mode connection, or a complete URL.

I want to pass string to this argument. One way to walk-around this problem is to write the string into temporary file and pass the file name. But I hope there is a straightforward way to convert string into connection.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `textConnection` like this (here with the `read.csv` function, but I guess `jags.model`  should work the same way) :

```
mytext <- "x,y\n1,2\n3,4"
read.csv(textConnection(mytext))
#   x y
# 1 1 2
# 2 3 4
```

Answer (score 2):

I would just add a small point about `textConnection`. I have occasionally ran into problems when I used `jags.model(textConnection(x)...)` inside a large for loop (i.e., more than 125 iterations or so). Essentially, it seems that the textConnections were being opened, but not closed, and then I would receive an error eventually after too may textConnections had been opened stating that `all connections are in use`.

I'm not entirely sure of the best solution, but I assume you could do something like:

```
zz <- textConnection(x)
jags.model(zz, ...)
close(zz)
```